# How to order records by hours from 7 to 6:55?

Tags: mysql

How to sort records in mysqli by a custom start time:

For example in the table below i want to sort by date with the exception that the 'start' of every day is to be 7AM and not 12AM.

[image]

Comment: Whilst imugr values my privacy I don't feel the same about their cookies. Can you add sample data as text to the question please.

Comment: How are you currently sorting your records?  What is your `ORDER BY` clause and how is it not working as expected?

Comment: but when i will ad new task to list the id is higher so is problem

Comment: I don't see any "next day" records... all belong to same day

Comment: @David   below is my result i want 7:00 row on first in my table https://imgur.com/a/IS7tupp    I start my checklist at 7:00 everyday so this task should be first

Comment: How does 2019-10-15 22:22:00 get a lower id than 2019-10-15 07:00:00?

Comment: @SalmanA everyday checklist is same

Comment: @Felipe: The keyword you're looking for is `ORDER BY`.  Use it in your `SELECT` queries to sort the results of those queries.  A quick Google search for "mysql order by" finds references and examples: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: @david  result is here https://imgur.com/a/IS7tupp    it start since 00:05 not 7:00...

Comment: @Felipe: It's not clear what part of this you aren't hearing... Your *query* (which you aren't showing us) needs an *"order by" clause* (which you aren't showing us).  If the results of your query are not ordered the way you expect, then *what query are you using* and *what ordering do you expect*?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a trivial order by on the concatenated values of date and time

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key, time time, dt date);

insert into t(dt,time) values
('2019-10-15' ,'05:00:00'),
('2019-10-16' ,'06:55:00'),
('2019-10-15' ,'22:00:00'),
('2019-10-15' ,'07:55:00');

select * from t
order by concat(dt,time);

+----+----------+------------+
| id | time     | dt         |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | 05:00:00 | 2019-10-15 |
|  4 | 07:55:00 | 2019-10-15 |
|  3 | 22:00:00 | 2019-10-15 |
|  2 | 06:55:00 | 2019-10-16 |
+----+----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If this is not what you want then you need to put a bit more work into the question.

Comment: id is auto incremented so when i will add new record with NEW hour then i have problem with chronology in ORDER BY ID...  look on screen https://imgur.com/a/ADA8LvE

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you in example https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uEuc.jpg, you need your tasklist to start at 7AM.

Please check and see if this works for you. 
Sqlfiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b725c/1

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int auto_increment primary key, time time);

insert into t(time) values
('00:05:00'),
('05:50:00'),
('07:00:00'),
('13:00:00'),
('19:00:00'),
('23:55:00');

select * from t 
order by 
case when time < '07:00:00' then 1 end asc, time;
```

Answer (score 0):

@skelwa do you know how to order by sedcond column Date ?

so i have this sql and i need to add order by date also.. For example I need  records from 2019-10-24  and after that 2019-10-25 from 7 to 6:55
select * from t 
order by 
case when time < '07:00:00' then 1 end asc, time;